# Identify n consecutive values from a column with the rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe where I have set one column larger than another column.

```
df['y'] = (df['a'] > df['b']).astype(int)
```

from this i got a new column with 1 and 0. Now I would like to get out with the rolling window function all columns, where the 1 9 is repeated consecutively and then the applicable values from the column df['a'] copied into a new column and fill the not applicable rows with nan

```
   a         b         y    z
-0.143    -0.109       0    nan
-0.109    -0.108       1    nan
-0.118    -0.108       1    nan
-0.118    -0.113       1    nan
-0.090    -0.110       0    nan
-0.090    -0.108       0    nan
-0.075    -0.050       1    -0.075
-0.075    -0.059       1    -0.075 
-0.065    -0.056       1    -0.065
-0.065    -0.053       1    -0.065
-0.042    -0.040       1    -0.042
-0.042    -0.039       1    -0.042
-0.064    -0.060       1    -0.064
-0.064    -0.057       1    -0.064
-0.055    -0.054       1    -0.055
-0.055    -0.053       1    -0.055
-0.068    -0.069       0    nan
-0.068    -0.056       1    nan
-0.074    -0.075       0    nan
-0.063    -0.076       0    nan
-0.074    -0.056       1    nan
-0.063    -0.069       0    nan
-0.077    -0.075       1    nan
-0.077    -0.050       1    nan
-0.082    -0.058       1    nan
-0.127    -0.056       1    nan
-0.095    -0.100       0    nan
-0.095    -0.094       1    nan
-0.108    -0.096       1    nan
```

Comment: please provide an example of the input and the expected output

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have edited the question again and added a snippet from the dataframe

Comment: @Schemih great, can you also point out which values should be set in the z column?

Comment: Thanks very mouch guys! the condition for taking over the value is not only the 1 but also that the one occurs at least 9 times in consecutive order

Comment: Then my answer should work for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, count the number of consecutive 1s, and set up a mask:

```
N = 9
# identify non-1s
m1 = df['y'].ne(1)
# calculate the number of consecutive 1s and check if ≥ N
m2 = df.groupby(m1.cumsum())['y'].transform('size').gt(N) # or .sub(1).ge(N)
# copy a if the above matches
df['z'] = df['a'].where(~m1&m2)
```

For fun, alternative with `rolling`:

```
N = 9
m1 = df['y'].rolling(N, min_periods=1).sum().eq(N)
m2 = m1[::-1].astype(int).rolling(N, min_periods=1).max().eq(1)

df['z'] = df['a'].where(m2)
```

output:

```
        a      b  y      z
0  -0.143 -0.109  0    NaN
1  -0.109 -0.108  1    NaN
2  -0.118 -0.108  1    NaN
3  -0.118 -0.113  1    NaN
4  -0.090 -0.110  0    NaN
5  -0.090 -0.108  0    NaN
6  -0.075 -0.050  1 -0.075
7  -0.075 -0.059  1 -0.075
8  -0.065 -0.056  1 -0.065
9  -0.065 -0.053  1 -0.065
10 -0.042 -0.040  1 -0.042
11 -0.042 -0.039  1 -0.042
12 -0.064 -0.060  1 -0.064
13 -0.064 -0.057  1 -0.064
14 -0.055 -0.054  1 -0.055
15 -0.055 -0.053  1 -0.055
16 -0.068 -0.069  0    NaN
17 -0.068 -0.056  1    NaN
18 -0.074 -0.075  0    NaN
19 -0.063 -0.076  0    NaN
20 -0.074 -0.056  1    NaN
21 -0.063 -0.069  0    NaN
22 -0.077 -0.075  1    NaN
23 -0.077 -0.050  1    NaN
24 -0.082 -0.058  1    NaN
25 -0.127 -0.056  1    NaN
26 -0.095 -0.100  0    NaN
27 -0.095 -0.094  1    NaN
28 -0.108 -0.096  1    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very mouch! it worked. It would be interesting to implement this also in a For loop so that you can link several conditions. For example if the values are successively 0, then copy to another column

Comment: No, you should (almost) never use for loops with pandas, this is **slow** ;)

Comment: oh okay. I am pretty new with pandas. But I'll keep that in mind. maybe I'll try to define a function for it so I can use that elsewhere too

Comment: Yes, that's a much better practice ;)